# The Meaning of C++ Quotes in g++ vs. MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

There's probably a Google search that'll answer this question but for the life of me, I can't think of one that doesn't get millions of unrelated answers.

So,

In MSVC text inside quotes "like this" is taken, I think, as a std::string or, maybe, std::string&.  In g++/gcc it always seems to be taken as const char*.  True?

I found a code snippet I wanted to play with and it contains

```
if(NULL == key)
   throw exception("Empty key");
```

compiles just fine in MSVC/VC++(2008( but when I try it on g++ (4.4.3) I get

```
no matching functions for calls to std::exception::exception(const char&)
```

I got this to work:

```
if (NULL == key)
{
   std::string   estr   ("Empty key");
   throw exception("Empty key");
}
```

But that's just plain ugly.

This got me different errors:

```
std::string   estr   ("");
if (NULL == key)
{
   estr = "Empty key";
   throw exception("Empty key");
}
```

I have no clue what exception() expects as its input.  I did find something that suggested std::string or maybe std::string& but I lost that page and the millions of unhelpful pages I've found since are, well, useless.  Have all kinds of info on exception class, exception use,....

Short of my ugly fix, is there a simple way to tell g++ that "this is a std::string" not a const char& and still keep VC++ happy?  (obviously I'm trying to do cross compilable code from single source.)

And for that matter, how id

```
   throw exception("Empty key");
```

different from

```
   throw "Empty key";
```

Thanks,

Wes

Comment: throw exception(new std::string("Empty key"));

Comment: @DrewBurchett: `exception` has no non-default constructors, so that won't work, even if creating a memory leak was a good idea (which it isn't).

Comment: @MikeSeymour:  OK, maybe I'm misunderstanding.  Is the compiler not telling him that exception is expecting a std::string?  And if that is the case, how would you throw an exception passing in a std::string that would then be destroyed since control will never be passed back to any point beyond the exception?

Comment: @DrewBurchett: The error is saying that there's no matching constructor, and doesn't say what is expected. The standard subclasses of `exception` such as `runtime_error` store a copy of the string they're initialised with, which lasts as long as the exception object itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string literal always has the type of an array of `char`, with a size just large enough to contain the characters in the literal with a null terminator. So `"Empty key"` has the type `char[10]`. This can be implicitly converted to either `char const *` or `std::string` if required.

The error is because `exception` is intended as a base class for exception types, not something you instantiate directly. You should throw one of the types defined in `<stdexcept>` such as `std::runtime_error` (which can be constructed using a string), or define your own type that inherits `std::exception` and overrides `what()`.

I'm guessing that Microsoft has added a non-standard constructor to `std::exception`. They like to extend the language in strange ways.

Comment: it's perfectly legal for Microsoft to add a non-standard constructor, especially since it's intended to be used as a base type for other exceptions in the standard library. Since they're part of the Standard Library implementation, those other exceptions may use implementation-specific methods of their base classes. it's even common to use implementation-specific base classes.

Comment: @MSalters: Of course it's legal, and I'm sure someone could come up with a reasonable justification for making it public if they wanted to. It's just a bad idea from a portability viewpoint (as evidenced by this question).

Comment: It looks like g++ also has a non-standard constructor for `std::exception`. Otherwise, the second example in the question would not compile.

Comment: @Gorpik: It looks like the old version used by the OP did (assuming the posted code did indeed compile, and there wasn't another type called `exception` hiding `std::exception`); more recent versions, since at least 4.4.5, don't.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I based my comment on OP's question, since I had no reason not to trust him. Either he is wrong with his second example or g++ have done a quite unusual thing, namely removing a feature in a minor release which may break existing code.

Answer (score 2):

std::exception is the base class.

Try throwing a std::runtime_error instead.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid throwing exceptions by type `std::string` because they themselves can throw an exception.And if that happens you end up with an **Undefined Behavior**.

Throw standard exceptions defined in `<stdexcept>` or have your own exception class derive from `std::exception` class and throw it.And override the `what()` method to add appropriate description of the exception.

Also, Always `throw` by value and `catch` by reference.

Answer (score 0):

`"like this"` is always regarded as an array of `const char`, according to the standard. This is not the problem here. What really happens is that `std::exception` only has the default constructor, once again according to the standard. It is usual to include an additional constructors taking a text string, but this constructor works differently in VC++ and g++, as your example shows.

I haven't got the g++ documents here but, from your examples, it looks like it defines that non-standard constructor as:

`explicit exception(const std::string&);`

while VC++ defines the non-standard constructor as:

`explicit exception(const char*);`